# Sign Enumeration

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, generating-functions, integer-programming

What is the number of solutions of $(a_i)_{i=1}^n$ such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^nia_i\le b,\quad a_i\in\{-1,1\},\quad \sum_{i=1}^n{a_i}=c$$
given $b,c\in\mathbf Z$?

Is there a generating function solution?

Comment: Did you meanwhile formulate an answer to this question yourself? If so, would you mind to share it with us? I'm quite curious, you know ..

Comment: @HandeBruijn: I did have an generating function solution the same as that presented in http://mathoverflow.net/a/247319/32660, which I did not find helpful in enumeration than other direct method like recursive method. The answerer Max Alekseyev draws the same conclusion as he stated in the comments.